# Не работают сессии в joomla

Tags: php, joomla, сессия

Ситуация такая: Есть 2 материала: regis и profil, есть ajax скрипт, который подключен к regis, есть обработчик формы, которая отправляется через ajax, на saveUser.php. Если использовать следующий код, то всё работает как надо (все проверки срабатывают, всё сохраняется, с regis на profil переходит).

regis:

```
<div id="result_form"> </div>
<form id="reg_form" class="form" action="" method="POST">
<div class="form-group"><label>Ваш логин для входа на сайт:</label><br /> <input class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="login" type="text" placeholder="Your login..." data-validate="" /><span class="hint">Обязательно для заполнения</span></div>
<div class="form-group"><label>Ваш пароль:</label><br /> <input class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Your pASS..." data-validate="" /><span class="hint">Обязательно для заполнения</span></div>
<div class="form-group"><label>Ваша должность:</label><br /> <input class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="position" type="text" placeholder="Your position..." data-validate="" /><span class="hint">Обязательно для заполнения</span></div>
<div class="form-group"><label>Ваше место работы:</label><br /> <input class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="placeJob" type="text" placeholder="Your place job..." data-validate="" /><span class="hint">Обязательно для заполнения</span></div>

<div class="form-group"><input id="reg_btn" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" /></div></form>
```

profil - здесь из сессии должно выводиться значение через плагин sourcerer

```
{source} <?php
echo("Hello");
?> {/source}
```

ajax:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#reg_btn").click(
        function(ev){
          ev.preventDefault();
          var forma = $("#reg_form");
          var field = [];
          var leng = 0;
          forma.find('input[data-validate]').each(function() {
            field.push('input[data-validate]');
            var value = $(this).val();
            var line = $(this).closest('.form-group');
              if(!value){
                line.addClass('emptyField');
                setTimeout(function() {
                  line.removeClass('emptyField')
                }.bind(this),3000);
              }else{leng++;}            
          });
          if(leng == field.length){
            sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'reg_form', 'http://ip/nameSite/templates/bootstrap4/dopScripts/saveUser.php');
            return false;            
          }
        }
    );
});

function sendAjaxForm(result_form, reg_form, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     url, 
        type:     "POST", 
        dataType: "html", //формат данных
        data: $("#"+reg_form).serialize(),  
        success: function(response) { 
          result = $.parseJSON(response);
          if(result.already == "True"){
            var message = document.getElementById('result_form');
            message.innerHTML = "<p style='color: red;'>Такой логин уже существует</p>";            
            message.scrollIntoView();
          }else{
            window.location.href = 'moj-profil';            
          }
        },
        error: function(response) {
            $('#result_form').html('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
        }
    });
}
```

saveUser.php:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login']; if ($login == '') { unset($login);} }
  if (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password = $_POST['password']; if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }
  if (isset($_POST['position'])) { $position = $_POST['position']; if ($position =='') { unset($position);}}
  if (isset($_POST['placeJob'])) { $placejob = $_POST['placeJob']; if ($placejob =='') { unset($placejob);}}  
  include('bd.php');
  $checkUser="SELECT nick FROM registration WHERE nick = ?";
  $query = $db->prepare($checkUser);
  $query->bind_param("s", $login);
  $query->execute();
  $query->store_result();
  $query->bind_result($check_email);
  $query->fetch();
  $empty = $query->num_rows();
  if($empty != 0){
    $already="True";
    $result = array('already'=>$already);
  }else{
    $insert = "INSERT INTO registration (nick, pass, position, placejob)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $qinsert = $db->prepare($insert);
    $qinsert->bind_param("ssss", $login, $password, $position, $placejob);
    $qinsert->execute();
    $already="False";
    //THIS PLACE 
    $result = array(
        'already' => $already,
        'login' => $login
    );
  }
  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Теперь проблема. В очень многих источниках указывается, что обычные сессии конструкции `session_start(); $_SESSION['']` в jooml-е не работают и надо использовать следующие конструкции:

Для записи в сессию

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('myVar', array('login'=>$login, 'first'=>1));
```

Для получения сессии:

```
{source} <?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php');
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$mySess = $session->get('myVar', array());
echo("Hello $mySess");//Результат Hello Array
foreach($mySess as $one){
echo("Hello".$one['login']." ".$one['first']);//Результат пуст
}
?> {/source}
```

Но это не срабатывает потому, что если код записи в сессию вставить на `//THIS PLACE` в файле saveUser.php, или любое другое место, то в БД всё будет записано, но ajax не переправит на новую страницу и скажет, что `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end in JSON`, если использовать `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` или `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON`, если использовать `define('_JEXEC', 1);`.
*В joomle я новичок и очень много не знаю.* Можете подсказать как исправить эту ошибку, *чтобы сессии нормально подключались, сохранялись и работали?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, проблема была в `define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`. Неправильно указывался путь до файла. Пытался сделать и `define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) )` и прочие аналоги, но они указывали папку с файлом, к которой потом пытались обратиться через `require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php')`. Такого пути соответственно не было и нужно взять корень сервера и исправить на это:`define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nameSite")`. Ну и заключительный рабочий код такой.

Для записи в сессию:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nameSite"); 
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$string = JFactory::getSession();
$string->set('some',array('mass'=>123,'data'=>$data));
```

Для получения сессии:

```
{source}

<?php
$data = JFactory::getSession();
$data2 = $data->get('some', array());
echo "first ". (string)$data2['mass']." second ".(string)$data2['data'];
?>
{/source}
```